# want to build web site by django for take a value by Temperature sensor on particle-Photon

Tags: python, django, particles

i want to build an web site by djnago. this site could be able to take values from Temperature sensor which is connection with my particle-Photon. i checked the net but i do not found an compatible libary Which could be connect my Photon and django framwork. is there any helpful libary to do this .
my "Temperature.ino" code:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
OneWire ds = OneWire(D4);  // 1-wire signal on pin D4

unsigned long lastUpdate = 0;

float lastTemp;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // Set up 'power' pins, comment out if not used!
  pinMode(D3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D5, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(D3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(D5, HIGH);
}

// up to here, it is the same as the address acanner
// we need a few more variables for this example

void loop(void) {
  byte i;
  byte present = 0;
  byte type_s;
  byte data[12];
  byte addr[8];
  float celsius, fahrenheit;

  if ( !ds.search(addr)) {
    Serial.println("No more addresses.");
    Serial.println();
    ds.reset_search();
    delay(250);
    return;
  }

  // The order is changed a bit in this example
  // first the returned address is printed

  Serial.print("ROM =");
  for( i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    Serial.write(' ');
    Serial.print(addr[i], HEX);
  }

  // second the CRC is checked, on fail,
  // print error and just return to try again

  if (OneWire::crc8(addr, 7) != addr[7]) {
      Serial.println("CRC is not valid!");
      return;
  }
  Serial.println();

  // we have a good address at this point
  // what kind of chip do we have?
  // we will set a type_s value for known types or just return

  // the first ROM byte indicates which chip
  switch (addr[0]) {
    case 0x10:
      Serial.println("  Chip = DS1820/DS18S20");
      type_s = 1;
      break;
    case 0x28:
      Serial.println("  Chip = DS18B20");
      type_s = 0;
      break;
    case 0x22:
      Serial.println("  Chip = DS1822");
      type_s = 0;
      break;
    case 0x26:
      Serial.println("  Chip = DS2438");
      type_s = 2;
      break;
    default:
      Serial.println("Unknown device type.");
      return;
  }

  // this device has temp so let's read it

  ds.reset();               // first clear the 1-wire bus
  ds.select(addr);          // now select the device we just found
  // ds.write(0x44, 1);     // tell it to start a conversion, with parasite power on at the end
  ds.write(0x44, 0);        // or start conversion in powered mode (bus finishes low)

  // just wait a second while the conversion takes place
  // different chips have different conversion times, check the specs, 1 sec is worse case + 250ms
  // you could also communicate with other devices if you like but you would need
  // to already know their address to select them.

  delay(1000);     // maybe 750ms is enough, maybe not, wait 1 sec for conversion

  // we might do a ds.depower() (parasite) here, but the reset will take care of it.

  // first make sure current values are in the scratch pad

  present = ds.reset();
  ds.select(addr);
  ds.write(0xB8,0);         // Recall Memory 0
  ds.write(0x00,0);         // Recall Memory 0

  // now read the scratch pad

  present = ds.reset();
  ds.select(addr);
  ds.write(0xBE,0);         // Read Scratchpad
  if (type_s == 2) {
    ds.write(0x00,0);       // The DS2438 needs a page# to read
  }

  // transfer and print the values

  Serial.print("  Data = ");
  Serial.print(present, HEX);
  Serial.print(" ");
  for ( i = 0; i < 9; i++) {           // we need 9 bytes
    data[i] = ds.read();
    Serial.print(data[i], HEX);
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.print(" CRC=");
  Serial.print(OneWire::crc8(data, 8), HEX);
  Serial.println();

  // Convert the data to actual temperature
  // because the result is a 16 bit signed integer, it should
  // be stored to an "int16_t" type, which is always 16 bits
  // even when compiled on a 32 bit processor.
  int16_t raw = (data[1] << 8) | data[0];
  if (type_s == 2) raw = (data[2] << 8) | data[1];
  byte cfg = (data[4] & 0x60);

  switch (type_s) {
    case 1:
      raw = raw << 3; // 9 bit resolution default
      if (data[7] == 0x10) {
        // "count remain" gives full 12 bit resolution
        raw = (raw & 0xFFF0) + 12 - data[6];
      }
      celsius = (float)raw * 0.0625;
      break;
    case 0:
      // at lower res, the low bits are undefined, so let's zero them
      if (cfg == 0x00) raw = raw & ~7;  // 9 bit resolution, 93.75 ms
      if (cfg == 0x20) raw = raw & ~3; // 10 bit res, 187.5 ms
      if (cfg == 0x40) raw = raw & ~1; // 11 bit res, 375 ms
      // default is 12 bit resolution, 750 ms conversion time
      celsius = (float)raw * 0.0625;
      break;

    case 2:
      data[1] = (data[1] >> 3) & 0x1f;
      if (data[2] > 127) {
        celsius = (float)data[2] - ((float)data[1] * .03125);
      }else{
        celsius = (float)data[2] + ((float)data[1] * .03125);
      }
  }

  // remove random errors
  if((((celsius <= 0 && celsius > -1) && lastTemp > 5)) || celsius > 125) {
      celsius = lastTemp;
  }

  fahrenheit = celsius * 1.8 + 32.0;
  lastTemp = celsius;
  Serial.print("  Temperature = ");
  Serial.print(celsius);
  Serial.print(" Celsius, ");
  Serial.print(fahrenheit);
  Serial.println(" Fahrenheit");

  // now that we have the readings, we can publish them to the cloud
  String temperature = String(fahrenheit); // store temp in "temperature" string
  Particle.publish("temperature", temperature, PRIVATE); // publish to cloud
  delay(5000); // 5 second delay
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can send data through HTTP from your photon(mostly, I've heard of it), and using HTTP calls you can push data to your Django application.
On Django side, use `djangorestfraework` for building APIs.

Comment: i checked net. HTTP will be helpful mostly.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any idea about Particle-Photon but basically your .ino extension shows that your file is Arduino file.

Arduino can be connected to python via serial communication.  In Django framework you can use that serial communication to get the temperature sensor data and return your logic applied data in JSON format ( by using django rest framework ) to get back data in arduino ( in your case particle photon ).